# Query with match to get all values for a given field! ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm pretty new to elastic search and would like to write a query for all of the values a specific field?  I mean, say i have a field "Number" and "change_manager_group", is there a query to perform list all the numbers of which "change_manager_group = Change Managers - 2"

```
  {
   "took" : 2,
   "timed_out" : false,
   "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 10,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
      "total" : 1700,
      "max_score" : 1.0,
      "hits" : [
        {
    "_index" : "test-tem-changes",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "CHG0393073_1554800400000",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "work_notes" : "",
      "priority" : "4 - Low",
      "planned_start" : 1554800400000,
      "Updated_by" : "system",
      "Updated" : 1554819333000,
      "phase" : "Requested",
      "Number" : "CHG0312373",
      "change_manager_group" : "Change Managers - 1",
      "approval" : "Approved",
      "downtime" : "false",
      "close_notes" : "",
      "Standard_template_version" : "",
      "close_code" : null,
      "actual_start" : 1554819333000,
      "closed_by" : "",
      "Type" : "Normal"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test-tem-changes",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "CHG0406522_0",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "work_notes" : "",
      "priority" : "4 - Low",
      "planned_start" : 0,
      "Updated_by" : "svcmdeploy_automation",
      "Updated" : 1553320559000,
      "phase" : "Requested",
      "Number" : "CHG041232",
      "change_manager_group" : "Change Managers - 2",
      "approval" : "Approved",
      "downtime" : "false",
      "close_notes" : "Change Installed",
      "Standard_template_version" : "",
      "close_code" : "Successful",
      "actual_start" : 1553338188000,
      "closed_by" : "",
      "Type" : "Automated"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test-tem-changes",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "CHG0406526_0",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "work_notes" : "",
      "priority" : "4 - Low",
      "planned_start" : 0,
      "Updated_by" : "svcmdeploy_automation",
      "Updated" : 1553321854000,
      "phase" : "Requested",
      "Number" : "CHG0412326",
      "change_manager_group" : "Change Managers - 2",
      "approval" : "Approved",
      "downtime" : "false",
      "close_notes" : "Change Installed",
      "Standard_template_version" : "",
      "close_code" : "Successful",
      "actual_start" : 1553339629000,
      "closed_by" : "",
      "Type" : "Automated"
    }
  },
```

I tried this after a bit of googling, but that errors out

```
curl -XGET  "http://localhost:9200/test-tem-changes/_search?pretty=true" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
> {
>     "query" : { "Number" : {"query" : "*"} }
> }
> '
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

To get all the documents where `change_manager_group ==Change Managers - 2` you want to use a [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/query-dsl-term-query.html). Below I am wrapping it in a `filter` context so that it is faster (does not score relevance).

If `change_manager_group` is not a `keyword` mapped field, you may have to use `change_manager_group.keyword` depending on your mapping.

```
GET test-tem-changes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "change_manager_group": "Change Managers - 2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```